# Javascript que substitui

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho um código JavaScript que supostamente devia de substituir o assinalado abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A plataforma desse chatbox é a FORUMEIROS e o código que estou utilizando é o seguinte:

```
   $(window).load(function() {
      var chatbox_script = function() {
        var overrided = Chatbox.prototype.refresh;
        Chatbox.prototype.refresh = function(data) {
          overrided.call(this, data);
          $('.chatbox-username').each(function(){
            this.previousSibling&&$.trim(this.previousSibling.nodeValue)=="@"&&$(this.previousSibling).replaceWith('<img src="http://i.imgur.com/zICIAne.png" /> ')
          })
        };
      };
      var s=document.createElement('script');s.text="("+chatbox_script.toString()+")();";$('object[data^="/chatbox/index.forum"],iframe[src^="/chatbox/index.forum"]').each(function(){try{$(this.contentDocument||this.contentWindow.document).find("#chatbox").closest("html").find("head").first().each(function(){this.appendChild(s.cloneNode(true))})}catch(a){}})
    });
```

Será que o código tem algum erro?

Comment: aquele @ era pra ser substituído por uma imagem ? dê uma identada melhor nesse código javascript por favor.

Comment: Abra o console do navegador do Chrome, na aba "console" coloque um 'console.log($.trim(this.previousSibling.nodeValue))` dentro desse `$('.chatbox-username').each(function(){ ... })` e veja o que ele retorna. Pelo que estou vendo esse código vem um minify.

Comment: Não retornou nada. E sim, é suposto substituir @ pela imagem que se encontra no código. > http://i.imgur.com/zICIAne.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara, tenta desse modo, sou meio amador mas talvez ajude:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  var chatbox_script = function() {
    var overrided = Chatbox.prototype.refresh;
    Chatbox.prototype.refresh = function(data) {
      overrided.call(this, data);
      $('.chatbox-username').each(function(){
        this.previousSibling&&$.trim(this.previousSibling.nodeValue)=='<img src="http://i.imgur.com/zICIAne.png" />'&&$(this.previousSibling).replaceWith("@")
      })
    };
  };
  var s=document.createElement('script');s.text="("+chatbox_script.toString()+")();";$('object[data^="/chatbox/index.forum"],iframe[src^="/chatbox/index.forum"]').each(function(){try{$(this.contentDocument||this.contentWindow.document).find("#chatbox").closest("html").find("head").first().each(function(){this.appendChild(s.cloneNode(true))})}catch(a){}})
});
```

Comment: @Fábio Ferreira deu certo cara?

Comment: Deu sim. Havia esquecido de dizer. Desculpa ^^